# Login in Google Colab with Oauth2

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to login in a Google Colab notebook with Oauth 2.0 but the Google login web page that is launched ends in a non-existent web `(http://localhost:8090/?code=4/NAFDWUxkOxp3FIlB9I_vxFTFm-zjAx0XJpEspQ9dGozG-0L3ccthFD12FAhq_B5hLWTxDFuUg_SjC011V9jiLDw&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings)`.

Maybe the error is related with any callback url, but I don't know how to fix that.

This is the code I used for the login.

```
import os
os.environ['USE_NATIVE_IPYTHON_SYSTEM_COMMANDS'] = '1'

import httplib2

from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow
from oauth2client import tools

from google.colab import drive; drive.mount('/content/drive')

PATH_BASE = '/content/drive/My Drive/.../'
CLIENT_SECRET = PATH_BASE + 'client_secret_event.json'
SCOPES = [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings"]
STORAGE = Storage(PATH_BASE + 'credentials.storage')
flags = tools.argparser.parse_args([])

# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
def authorize_credentials():
    # Fetch credentials from storage
    credentials = STORAGE.get()
    # If the credentials doesn't exist in the storage location then run the flow
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, scope=SCOPES)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        credentials = run_flow(flow, STORAGE, flags, http=http)
    return credentials

credentials = authorize_credentials()
```

Any idea about why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of how using **InstalledAppFlow** to use Google Docs with python :

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
```

Useful links:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications (with full example)](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/oauth-installed.md)

[Sample Using Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [installed application flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) rather than a web apps flow.

The reason is that Colab backends are not directly exposed to the Internet and hence cannot handle URL redirects common to web-based OAuth flows.

Comment: Is there any example of that using oauth2client library or any other similar? I can't find any solution in that documentation

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

Answer (score 0):

Following both comments and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-emails-from-gmail-using-gmail-api-in-python/) tutorial (you can benefit from it to create the application in the console), I achieved the following code:

```
creds = None

# Check if previous log-in exists
if os.path.exists('/content/drive/MyDrive/Projects/xyz/token.pickle'):
  with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Projects/xyz/token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
    creds = pickle.load(token)

# If not available or invalid, log in using the "console" InstalledAppFlow
if not creds or not creds.valid:
  if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
    creds.refresh(Request())
  else:
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('/content/drive/MyDrive/Projects/xyz/credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_console()

  # Save the access token in token.pickle file for the next run
  with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Projects/xyz/token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
    pickle.dump(creds, token)

# Connect to the Gmail API
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console' resolution - use right versions, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829631/953553

Comment: but still you will end with The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure. Follow the Out-of-Band (OOB) flow migration guide linked in the developer docs below to migrate your app to an alternative method.  so still no chance to work https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration?hl=en