# 【Google OAuth】AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

I wrote a Python script(Google_add.py) which creates users in the Google Workspace. However, When it is run, an AttributeError occurred. How do I resolve this Error?

・Google_add.py　(Excerpt）

```
PATH = '/opt/Google/credentials.json'
CLIENT_SECRETS = '/opt/Google/client_secrets.json'
credentials = None

#If there are credentials
if os.path.exists(PATH):
    credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(
      path = PATH,
      scopes = SCOPES)

#If there are no (valid) credentials available
if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
    if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
      credentials.refresh(Request())
    else:
      FLOW = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file = CLIENT_SECRETS,
        scopes = SCOPES)
      credentials = FLOW.run_console()
    with open(PATH, 'w') as token:
      token.write(credentials.to_json())
```

・Error Message

```
File "Google_add.py", line 186, in <module>
main()
File "Google_add.py", line 172, in main
FLOW.run_console()
AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'
```

I refer the below site when I wrote it.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-installed.md#sending-users-to-googles-oauth-20-server
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python?hl=en

In the script, I want to authorize using the user account(not service account). And "run_local_server()" method doesn't work because my linux server isn't a web server (doesn't have httpd, nginx and so on).

(I'm sorry if my writing is hard to read.)

Comment: In any case, have you seen this [github](https://github.com/xyou365/AutoRclone/issues/101) post that has the same problem as yours? One of the comments suggested that the versions of installed packages be changed.

Comment: Thank you! The script runs successfully by changing the versions of google-api-python-client, google-auth, google-auth-httplib2, and google-auth-oauthlib.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, let me compose it as an answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue may have been a version compatibility issue of `google-api-python-client` library with other libraries like

- google-auth
- google-auth-httplib2
- google-auth-oauthlib

You just need to make sure that the version of your `google-api-python-client` supports the versions you have installed to its dependency libraries.
You can view the full change log of `google-api-python-client` library [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/3fb2a386892a695a0a7be33b499b37a9a75b2439/CHANGELOG#L17)

### References:

[google-api-python-client change log](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/3fb2a386892a695a0a7be33b499b37a9a75b2439/CHANGELOG#L17)

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/auth.html

https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/oauth.html

[google-api-python-client](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/)

[google_auth_oauthlib.flow module](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html)

[Github post similar issue](https://github.com/xyou365/AutoRclone/issues/101)

Comment: This solution is outdated. It will result in a 400 error from Google OAuth.

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on George's answer above, the versions of the library from the github post that work are:

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.2
google-auth==1.8.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
```

Answer (score 5):

You said:

> "run_local_server()" method doesn't work because my linux server isn't
> a web server (doesn't have httpd, nginx and so on).

This isn't true. The solution below will work also on non-web servers, your local machine, local scripts etc... However, you need a way to open a browser. If not, you can create the token on your local machine and copy the token to your server.

Replace:
`credentials = FLOW.run_console()`

with:
`credentials = FLOW.run_local_server(port=0)`

This will work perfectly in all situations.

For more info, refer to https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0):

> The `run_console()` (OOB) flow has been deprecated by Google, that's why it was removed from newer versions of the Google OAuth connector

https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html?m=1#disallowed-oob

Replace the line

```
credentials = FLOW.run_console()
```

to

```
credentials = FLOW.run_local_server()
```

---

---

people also got it working by these configurations:

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.2
google-auth==2.14.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
```

git link : https://github.com/xyou365/AutoRclone/issues/101#issuecomment-1795530261

Answer (score 0):

Replace: `credentials = FLOW.run_console()`

with: `credentials = FLOW.run_local_server(port=0)`

This worked. Thank you very much Ton Snoei.