# headless authentification of an app to google api

Tags: python, google-api, headless

I have a python app which needs (among many other things) to read a googlesheet.
The line

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(cred_file, SCOPES)
```

requires me to visit `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=...`
I go there, give a manual authorization and my app works well.

Now, here is the twist.

I need to run the app on a headless machine. I only have a ssh access. It still requires me to visit `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/a`, but I don't know how to get to that URL with my "only ssh" machine.

I could go there with a text base browser[1], but I'd like a more "programmatic" way.

[1] w3m and elinks do not work because of a lack of javascript. I did not got further in that direction.

EDIT : when I said "read googlesheet", I was oversimplifying my needs. In fact I have (among others) to list elements in a shared drive.

Comment: Have you looked at using [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/)? That is generally what I use when I need to pull and save data to a google sheet programmatically in python. You just need to share the google sheet with the `client_email` in your credentials.json file.

Comment: Well. I was oversimplifying. In my real live I need much more than reading a googlesheet. By the way, thanks for gspread -- I may need it for other projects.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution ?

Comment: @gowerc I ran the app for 2 minutes on my own computer, made the authorization. This produces a json token file that I copied to the destination. I'm far from being sure that this is a correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change its next line from `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` to `credentials = flow.run_console()`.

But, this doesn't work on latest version of `google-api-python-client` library. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75829631), these versions work.

`google-api-python-client==1.7.2` `google-auth==1.8.0` `google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3` `google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1`