# python error AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console' - when authenticating for google API on google colab

Tags: python, authentication, google-api, google-colaboratory

I have been using a python script which I run from Google Colab to generate documents for about a year now.
Nothing was changed to my code (and I double checked this by testing an older
version of the program which gave me the same problem) but since the last few days
I keep getting an error that I can't resolve.

This is the relevant part of the program:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os.path
from datetime import date, timedelta
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import googleapiclient.discovery as discovery
from httplib2 import Http
import google.auth
import datetime as datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
import pytz

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']


creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)

# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            '/content/drive/MyDrive/geneeskunde/The_administrator/credentials.json', SCOPES)
        
        auth_uri = flow.authorization_url()
        # Redirect the user to auth_uri on your platform.

            
        #creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        #The following line allowed me to authenticate through Google Colab:
        creds = flow.run_console()
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

#Build services required for the google API's:
peopleservice = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
driveservice = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
docservice = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
sheetservice = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```

The error I get in Google Colab is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-8d35889d45f8> in <cell line: 211>()
    220 
    221         #creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
--> 222         creds = flow.run_console()
    223     # Save the credentials for the next run
    224     with open('token.json', 'w') as token:

AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'
```

I tried to solve this issue myself and on [【Google OAuth】AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602866/google-oauth-attributeerror-installedappflow-object-has-no-attribute-run-cothey) describe exactly this problem with the following solution:

```
Expanding on George's answer above, the versions of the library from the github post that work are:

google-api-python-client==1.7.2
google-auth==1.8.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
```

I tried installing these versions on my colab session using

```
!pip install google-api-python-client==1.7.2
!pip install google-auth==1.8.0
...
```

Unfortunately the same error reappeared.

I found extra info on the run_console function on this site:
https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html

But I can't seem to fix this issue.

Any help or insight would be most appreciated.

Regards,

Usui

Answer (score 0):

The run_console (OOB) flow has been deprecated and removed from the library.
See: https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html?m=1#disallowed-oob

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).